# Localhost in URL = numeric?

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, hyperlinks

I understand the reasoning for the error message, I'm just a little unsure about the wording of it:

> Links cannot contain 'localhost' (try a non-numeric domain)

[image: bug]

Comment: At a guess, the error message is "Links cannot contain '{badurl}' (try a non-numeric domain)", and someone added localhost to the list of bad-urls...

Comment: localhost is a shortcut to 127.0.0.1 that's the reason it's considered "numeric domain".

Comment: @Benjol any URL which contains the IP address of a server can't be inserted to posts as link, not even valid. The validator doesn't perform any "ping" just block any URL of that kind. (try it yourself: http://198.252.206.16 which point to Stack Exchange server yet can't be inserted to posts)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Every valid host/domain name is a shortcut to an IP address. If you're saying localhost is just shorthand (an abbreviation?) for 127.0.0.1, that's not the case; it sometimes resolves to ::1. I'm not saying localhost URLs should be allowed, but there's no good reason for this particular error message to be shown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ultimately, you're adding a *link* to your post that nobody will be able to click on; all it is saying is: it doesn't make much sense as a hyper-link, but will be fine for example as code: `http://localhost:8080/whatever`.

We have, however, changed the error message to:

> Links cannot contain 'localhost' (try a full domain or wrap it in a code block).

Comment: What about "try a non-numeric and non-local domain"? For most people, "localhost" doesn't appear to be numeric/IP.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd agreed; this relates to some recently edited code - and I just want to check the intent with the author before diving in and hacking it.

Comment: Wasn't this filter in place from the beginning? I'm pretty sure I tried to enter link to `http://[IP-Address]` long ago and saw this exact message. Anyway, glad you agree thanks!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes; the code that detects the scenario and generates the error message has been changed. The test itself is not new.

Comment: I'm not adding a link, I'm adding text that describes the scenario.  Stackoverflow is interpreting some text that looks like an url to be a link.  It should apply the check when deciding whether to treat an url as a link- and not when it determines if my post is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following error message:

> Links cannot contain 'localhost' (try another, non-numeric domain)

This should make clear the user needs to try with another domain that is not numeric.

#### Update

The error message has been changed as follows:

> Links cannot contain 'localhost' (try a full domain or wrap it in a code block).

[image: screenshot]

That at least is the message you get when the URL contains localhost as domain name.

Comment: How do we actually wrap a localhost address in code to use it in stackexchange? I've tried indenting it with four spaces, enclosing it in <pre or <code, and keep getting the above error. Reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452524/how-to-download-all-files-from-ubuntu-one-in-14-04

Comment: Use \`http://localhost\`.

Comment: Enclosing it in bacticks was the trick. Much obliged, kiamlaluno.