# Please support IPv6 addresses in your URL parser (RFC 2732)

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

The geek in me wants to express the my web site as the IPv6 address `::1`. Unfortunately the software on the SE sites doesn't play along. It strips the brackets from the URL. I.e. `http://[::1]` becomes `http://::1` (as evidenced in my profile).

Could you please support the format described in [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)? Of course this isn't exactly a priority feature and I realize that. Would be still nice to have.

#### Quoted from section 2

> To use a literal IPv6 address in a URL, the literal address should be enclosed in "[" and "]" characters.  For example the following literal IPv6 address:
>
> ```
>  3ffe:2a00:100:7031::1
> ```
>
> would be represented as in the following example URL:
>
> ```
>  http://[3ffe:2a00:100:7031::1]
> ```

Comment: @kiamlaluno: thanks for the edit. Excellent idea.

Comment: I didn't add the quote; I just approved the edit. `:)` The thanks goes to @JamesDonnelly.

Comment: Oh yeah, indeeed. Sorry. And thanks to @JamesDonnelly :)

Answer (score 2):

We all have to make the transition to IP6, sooner or later.

If we are able to type in clickable URLs with IP6 addresses in all posts and comments, the Q&A process about this important and surprisingly slow-moving development will be a bit easier for everyone. With the clout that the SE network has in the IT world, it might even make a difference.

Looking forward to clickable IP6 URLs on the SE network!

Edited to add: A quick test [here](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php) of stackoverflow.com indicates that the SE network does not support IPv6, so maybe it is not realistic to push  this request before there is support for IPv6 from the SE sites. From a psychological (for want of a better word) perspective, not technical, of course.

Comment: But since numeric (clickable) URLs are [not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167525/localhost-in-url-numeric), I'd guess that numeric IPv6 URLs would meet the same fate.

Comment: `If we are able to type in clickable URLs with IP6 addresses in all posts and comments...` I don't see *any* reason for this. If you want to post an URL, use the address, not the IP. IPs change from time to time, that would effectively kill the link. Also it makes it unreadable and you don't know where that link will take you.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby the reason would be that during development and trouble shooting (two core activities for users of at least the IT-centered SE sites) often is easier with just a numeric address rather than having to go through a DNS. But I agree that numeric addresses are not eternal, but then again, neither are DNS records.

Comment: @Monolo: If you have a question which you need to link against *your* testing system, there's something wrong with the question.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: exactly that is bound to change (shifting IP addresses). It will probably happen again when you sign up with an ISP, because there are privacy concerns with IPv6 addresses as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: works in profiles ...

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby No one is talking about linking to test systems, so no need to imply that. Just saying that supporting IPv6 and its numeric representation of addresses would make a lot of sense, and personally I find that the clout of the SE network could provide a meaningful nudge in the right direction.